# Store char in array C not working properly

Tags: c, arrays, char

I have an array. But is not printing all the values when they are in my while loop. Is giving crazy a character. Any ideas.

```
    int x = 0;
    char a[3][20];


     strcpy(a[0], "Tires");
     strcpy(a[1], "Lights");
     strcpy(a[2], "Seats");

   while(statement here)
   {

      for(x = 0; x< 3; x++)
      {
         printf("%c type", a[x]);
      }
   }
```

Comment: How about posting some real, working code, that doesn't have things like `while(statement here)` in it?

Comment: Why are you trying to print a string as a char?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your printf should be like this:

```
printf("%s type\n", a[x]);
```

Because the elements of your array are strings.

after changing the `printf` statement like above your output:

**Output:**

```
Tires type
Lights type
Seats type
```

You can remove the `\n` in the `printf` that I added if you like . In that case here is the output:

```
Tires typeLights typeSeats type
```

Here is my code : ( Tyres should show in this implimentation )

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
 int x = 0;
 char a[3][20];


 strcpy(a[0], "Tires");
 strcpy(a[1], "Lights");
 strcpy(a[2], "Seats");

 while(1) // i left in this while as may be using it for something that you haven't shown in your code. 
 {        // But if you are not using while get rid of it .. its unnecessary 

   for(x = 0; x< 3; x++)
   {
      printf("%s type\n", a[x]);
   }
   break;
}

return 0;
```

}

here is how this code was run :

```
Notra:Desktop Sukhvir$ gcc -Werror -Wall -g -o try try.c -std=c99
Notra:Desktop Sukhvir$ ./try
Tires type
Lights type
Seats type
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your print to  `printf("%s type", a[x]);` 
Note the `%s` is for printing strings.

Comment: is not displaying the a[0] entry.

Comment: @Apollo see my answer to look at the output of the code

Answer (score 1):

`%c` is the format string for a single character, but you're passing a pointer to an array of characters - that is, a string.  Use `%s`:

```
printf("%s type\n", a[x]);
```

Your program as is causes undefined behaviour by mismatching the format string with the argument.

Comment: is not displaying the a[0] entry any ideas?

Comment: Given the code you've shown? No.

Comment: @Apollo *What* is not displaying `a[0]`? Your code or the code in this answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
int x = 0;
    char a[3][20];


     strcpy(a[0], "Tires");
     strcpy(a[1], "Lights");
     strcpy(a[2], "Seats");

   while(statement here)
   {

      for(x = 0; x< 3; x++)
      {
         printf("%s type", a[x]);
      }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its working fine.

a[0] entry is also being displayed.

[image]

Comment: of course we need to remove the 'while' thing.

Comment: Tempted to downvote for the gratuitously unnecessary screenshot.

Comment: It would also be good to point out your format string has been updated to use `"%s"` instead of `"%c"`.

Comment: @Paul Griffiths: unnecessary ? This screenshot makes him (Apollo) believe that there is nothing wrong in code. a[0] is being printed. He commented on two answers that a[0] is not being printed. thats why this screenshot.

Comment: @User42: You miss the point. You could have (and should have) just pasted a code block, instead of a screenshot.